# Store ajax result in jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-get

I started using jQuery and ajax to get data from database, but i cant find out how i can save result of $.get() into variable outside callback function.

This is my jquery script:

```
var result="";     
$.get("test.php", function(data){ result=data; });
alert(result);
```

This is test.php script:

```
echo "Hello, World";
```

Every time i run this script it alerts "".

Comment: post the test.php code

Comment: Can you first alert data inside your function. Make sure it returns any value.

Comment: @Gautam3164 he already has.

Comment: If i alert data in callback function it works; php file is <?php
echo "Hello, World";
?>

Comment: @Gautam3164 really? it says `echo "Hello, World";` right there...

Comment: Ok got it....sry I cnt saw it prevoiusly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = "";
$.get("test.php", function (data) {
    SomeFunction(data);
});

function SomeFunction(data) {
    result = data;
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well. My problem was probably $(document).ready() function.

Comment: You can simplify that further and just do: `$.get("test.php", SomeFunction);`

Answer (score 1):

Your alert will get fired before the `$.get` can return any data.

Make the alert run on an event instead - such as a click:

```
var result="";     
$.get("test.php", function(data){ result=data; });
<span onclick="alert(result);">show alert</span>
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much. Can you please explain me why i cant content of jquery script insert into $(document).ready(function(){}); Because when i do, it does not work.

Comment: Because the ajax request is asynchronous. Meaning it can take any amount of time to finish and `$.get` will return immediately, but your code assumed that the `$.get` call had fetched the result of `test.php` call before returning.