# PHP Var in Javascript from AJAX Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to get a php var from another page via ajax into javascript and it alerts nothing

PHP on getposY

```
<?php include"connectdatabase.php";
$posYquery=mysql_query("Select posY FROM multiplayer WHERE game = '1'");
$posY = mysql_fetch_array($posYquery);
$posY2 = $posY['posY']; 
?>
```

Javascript

```
function phpmove(){ 
$("#div1").load("getposY.php");
};
setInterval("phpmove()", 1);
var move = function(){
    canvasContext.clearRect(posX, posY, sizew, sizeh);
    var posY = "<?php echo $posY2; ?>";
    alert(posY);
    canvasContext.drawImage(player, posX, posY, sizew, sizeh);
};
setInterval(move, 1);
```

I do have a div with an id of div1
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, consider learning the difference between client and server side first.

Comment: thats not how ajax works.
your page is rendered first
var posY = "<?php echo $posY2; ?>"; is "" at this moment

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964734/store-ajax-result-in-jquery-variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP variable in JAVASCRIPT not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073130/php-variable-in-javascript-not-working) - Never ever duplicate your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

thats not how ajax works.
your page is rendered first
var posY = ""; is "" at this moment

see [Store ajax result in jQuery variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964734/store-ajax-result-in-jquery-variable)

so it should be more like (not tested):

your php file

```
<?php include"connectdatabase.php";
$posYquery=mysql_query("Select posY FROM multiplayer WHERE game = '1'");
$posY = mysql_fetch_array($posYquery);
echo $posY;
?>
```

your javascript file

```
var posY;
var move = function(){
    canvasContext.clearRect(posX, posY, sizew, sizeh);
    $.get("getposY.php", function (data) {
      posY=data;
    });
    alert(posY);
    canvasContext.drawImage(player, posX, posY, sizew, sizeh);
};
setInterval(move, 1);
```