# i need to reference an array created with .get()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to reference clues in a function later on in my code. How can i reference clues outside of the .git method?

```
$.get("clues.txt", function(data) 
 {
  var clues = data.split(',');
});
```

Comment: declare clues as a global variable..

Comment: Note that `$.get()` is an **asynchronous** operation. The callback function is called *when the HTTP request completes*. It's possible to arrange for the response data to be accessible outside the callback, but it won't be available immediately.

Comment: @DharaParmar - Making it global is a bad idea and is not recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store ajax result in jQuery variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964734/store-ajax-result-in-jquery-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably access `clues` outside the specific callback where its value is supplied.  Because the result is obtained via an asynchronous operation, the timing of the completion of that asynchronous operation is unknown.  Thus, the only place you can reliably use the result is inside the callback itself or in a function you call from within that callback and pass the value to.  This is how you do asynchronous programming.  You continue your programming sequence from within this callback.

```
$.get("clues.txt", function(data) {
    var clues = data.split(',');
    // other code goes here that uses the `clues` variable
});

// code here cannot use the `clues` variable because the asynchronous operation
// has not yet completed so the value is not yet available
```

Here are some other related answers:

[How do I get a variable to exist outside of this node.js code block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511533/how-do-i-get-a-variable-to-exist-outside-of-this-node-js-code-block/33511629#33511629)

[Node.JS How to set a variable outside the current scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799672/node-js-how-to-set-a-variable-outside-the-current-scope/32799727#32799727)

[How to capture the 'code' value into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036076/how-to-capture-the-code-value-into-a-variable/32037033#32037033)

Answer (score 0):

As per the reference of [Store ajax result in jQuery variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964734/store-ajax-result-in-jquery-variable). you can pass your response data to some further function. Moreover, you can also play with it by storing your response into your some `hidden` HTML input tag.

```
<input type="hidden" id="clues_data" value="">
```

So, in your `.get()` method you can do something like this:

```
$.get("clues.txt", function(data) 
 {
  $("#clues_data").val(data);
});
```

And then in your some further function you can access it like:

```
function someFurtherFunction(){
   var clues = $("#clues_data").val().split(',');
   // do something with clues
}
```

I know this is not the exact solution for your question, but I've tried to help you handle this situation. It may help some-other coder :)